# C++ STL map.find() not finding my stuff

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, find

I have constructed a map and loaded it with data. If I iterate over all the elements I see they are all valid. However, the find method doesn't find my item. I'm sure it's something stupid I am doing. Here is snippet:

```
// definitions
// I am inserting a person class and using the firstname as the key

typedef std::map<char*,Person *> mapType;
mapType _myMap;
mapType::iterator _mapIter;


...

Person *pers = new Person(FirstName, LastName, Address, Phone); 
_myMap.insert(make_pair(pers->firstName, pers);

...
```

...later....

```
_mapIter = _myMap.find(firstName); // returns map.end
_mapIter = _myMap.find("joe"); // returns map.end
```

and I have no idea why :(

Comment: What does `FirstName` hold? Is it the same variable as `firstName`? C++ is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the key is `char*`, they will be compared *by address*, not by value, e.g.

```
char* a = "123";
char* b = new char[4];
memcpy(b, a, 4);
assert(a != b);
```

You should use a `std::string`, which has an overloaded `<` for comparison by value.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Person*> mapType;
...
```

(And probably you want to use a `Person` or `shared_ptr<Person>` as the value to avoid memory leak.)

Comment: The key shouldn't be const (if you mean `const string`). Map will automatically make it const itself. If you mean using `char*` as the key, then yes, the map would make the pointer const, but you'd still be able to modify the string itself, thus blowing everything up.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to KennyTM's solution (std::string, which is really the better solution) is to tell map that it needs to use `strcmp()`, not `<`. However, the return value of `strcmp()`  isn't what `std::map` expects, it wants a boolean. So you need a thin wrapper function : `return strcmp(a,b) < 0;`